# Can't fetch jug 2.0.0 from Maven Central using Gradle

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, maven-central

We're switching build system from Ant to Gradle, mainly to benefit from the "automagic" dependency management. However, I'm having great problems resolving `jug 2.0.0`.

I've defined it in my `build.gradle` file like this:

```
compile 'org.safehaus.jug:jug:2.0.0'
```

which corresponds to the name of the artifact entry in Maven Central, but when I look in my Gradle cache only the `pom.xml` file has been downloaded - no jars.

Looking at [the artifact details on the Maven Central search page](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.safehaus.jug%7Cjug%7C2.0.0%7Cjar), it seems there are three files; `jug-2.0.0.pom`, `jug-2.0.0-asl.jar` and `jug-2.0.0-lgpl.jar`, where the difference between the latter two is the license (Apache Software License vs LGPL). I've tried adding `-asl` and `-lgpl` to the version number in the dependency specification, but it didn't help.

How do I correctly define this dependency, so that the jar files are downloaded and referenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'lgpl' part of the dependency is the classifier. Try to resolve it using:

```
dependencies{
    compile 'org.safehaus.jug:jug:2.0.0:lgpl'
}
```